# Is it okay to run regtest for dev purposes while simultaneously running a node on mainnet (bitcoind)?

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

Hope it won't mess anything up on my mainnet node.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your nodes are running on separate ports and using separate data directories, you should have no issues running multiple networks.

Note that you may run into resource issues, especially with regular spinning HDDs, if both networks have high requirements for disk writes and reads at any point.